# Devise "Creating New Session" is invoking Model's :on => :create validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Devise setup on a Rails Model:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
```

I also have validation on the same model:

```
before_validation :geocode_address, :on => :create
```

When I create new User the geocode_address gets called which is what I want to do but it also gets kicked when the user logs in (creates new Devise Session) which is what I don't want.

Do you know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens because the model gets validated on user log in as well. I think that it would be a better idea to utilize after_create on your model, like :

```
after_create :your_method

def your_method
  ...
end
```

Details : http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M000061